# Azure SQL Database Management GUI, where is it?

Tags: sql-server, user-interface, azure

Are we going back to green command prompts in place of the GUI. I like the cloud sql database but I also like the GUI of management studio of traditional SQL databases of the past. Its a major cut in productivity going back to scripting what you used to be able to see in a GUI. Visual Studio database designer fails almost 95% upon loading when connecting to an Azure cloud SQL database. In fact that surface designer will only load local databases and that is a 60 second plus struggle of crossing your fingers. So visual studio 2012 to 2013 is a not a valid until some awake folks at Microsoft decide to make that a working reality. 
What work a rounds are there to view and/or design cloud SQL databases. Keys, constraints indexes, etc..

Comment: Why can't you connect to SQL Management Studio using your Azure connection details?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do it by latest update of SSMS 2014

[SQL Server 2014 Management Studio - updated support for the latest Azure SQL Database Update V12 (preview)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx)